# Operator: "Are you through, Sir?" - AmEng vs. BrEng

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english

In the context of a telephone call via an [operator-assisted service](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_assistance), is it fact that in AmEng, if the operator asks the service user (caller) if ***they are through***, what is meant by that is, ***are you done/finished with your call***?

Thing is, considering that AmEng and BrEng share the idiomatic [***put someone/something through [to someone]***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+through), which  has the exact same meaning on both sides of the pond (i.e. *to connect someone/transfer someone's call [to someone]*), I can't seem to figure out why from the perspective of AmEng, the phrase ***are you through, Sir/Ma'am*** when used in such context, would mean anything different than ***are you connected, Sir/Ma'am***?

This is what it's all about:

> *Are you through?* (*telephone*)
>
> (*UK*) = are you connected
>
> (*U.S*) = are you finished/completed with your call
>
> [Selected Vocabulary Differences
>   Between British and American English](http://www.bu.edu/mfeldman/Slang/glossary.html)
>
> *Another Americanism which is by now quite well known in Britain, though it can still mislead if you are on the telephone and the American operator asks, **Are you through?** If you say 'Yes' (because you are connected) you are likely to be cut off.*
>
> [You Can't Say That! English Usage Today](https://books.google.fr/books?id=cXmXLi5O2hUC&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=%22operator%22+%22are+you+through%22++%22cut+off%22&source=bl&ots=l84q5lwFc9&sig=5gv0xquYhy1jBHiej6_6JpE9Cuk&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz6caO5tLLAhWLthoKHU5YDpAQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22operator%22%20%22are%20you%20through%22%20%20%22cut%20off%22&f=false)

FYI, these are not the only resources I've found that support a BrEng/AmEng difference in meaning of the phrase [***are you through***](https://books.google.fr/books?id=lqhKf4gU37wC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=%22are+you+through%22+%22connected%22+%22finished%22+american+english+british+difference&source=bl&ots=bfR3BLHHVM&sig=GrOyYq1AjbgUqiy7xdsXNXBcoio&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid2ZWrgdPLAhUILhoKHVy2CcQQ6AEIIzAD#v=onepage&q=%22are%20you%20through%22%20%22connected%22%20%22finished%22%20american%20english%20british%20difference&f=false) in the context of telecommunications.

Fact or baloney?

Comment: I can't remember when I last spoke to a telephone operator.

Comment: @KristinaLopez It's just used as an example. Please, see this link: https://books.google.fr/books?id=cXmXLi5O2hUC&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=%22operator%22+%22are+you+through%22++%22cut+off%22&source=bl&ots=l84q5lwCh6&sig=R5bqZR3Wp3Ce1gAuPJfKqN7bduw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-7O2V5dLLAhWFPBoKHWUFC0QQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22operator%22%20%22are%20you%20through%22%20%20%22cut%20off%22&f=false

Comment: It's the heading of your question so I'd take it to mean that that is specifically what you're asking about, Elian.  Ambiguous to a BrEng speaker?  Probably.  Nonsensical question to BrEng and AmEng speaker?  Probably.

Comment: I don't believe American operators would ever ask *"are you though, sir?"* I've never had a telephone operator ask me whether I've finished talking. For the last fifty years, Americans have signaled to the telephone company that they've finished talking by hanging up.

Comment: @PeterShor I would suspect that the difference of usage is pointed up here because operators in Britain ask (or once asked) callers "are you through" (=connected.) Considering that "through" in AmEng means among other things,"done/finished" (as in "I'm through with my homework"), which apparently is quite well known of BrEng speakers, the authors here are just assuming that the phrase "are you through" is also used by U.S. operators, but of course with a quite different meaning than in the UK.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I agree with your, ab2's and Peter's comments here. I too can't remember when an operator, even in the days when there were operators, ever asked me whether I was connected, or whether I was finished. The only thing I would say is that in Britain we seldom, if ever, use the verb *to be through* (*Are you through with using the photocopier*) as meaning *to be finished*. That is almost entirely American - in my experience. We might, however, say *Are you done with the copier*.

Comment: @WS2 Then, what would be the point of these authors underlining that usage distinction between BrEng and AmEng if "are you through (=connected)" is not even idiomatic in the UK?

Comment: Interesting point, but I agree with the only answer so far that “through” without “get” would probably be understood in most places as “finished” (and even with “get” the “finished” notion would probably still come through if someone asked impatiently “Have you **gotten** /Did you **get** through **with**  it yet?”).

Comment: @Elian this is some very old, and I suspect not well researched stuff that has got in here. Telephone operators? My children in their thirties wouldn't know what they were!

Comment: The net-net of this is that the idioms surrounding operator-assisted phone calls are so "stale" as to be nonexistent.  When (mythical) operators do, on rare occasions, actually speak to humans on the other end, they no doubt use language that has been chosen by the script writers to be unambiguous.

Comment: Operator? What's that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think *through* with the first  connotation you are suggesting is present mainly in the expression:

To ***[get through](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-through)***:

> - to be connected to a place by telephone:
>
>   - *I couldn’t get through – the line was engaged.
>       ***get through to***: I finally got through to Warren on his mobile.*

To be ***[through](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/through)*** both in AmE and BrE means:

> - having finished an activity or piece of work.
>
>   - *I’m not sure what time he’ll be through with his meeting.
>       Only one more letter to write. I’m nearly through*.

(Macmillan Dictionary)

Comment: These are denotations (even if to a degree metaphorical), not connotations. The definitions are agreed; the confusion arises because there is more than one definition.